# Locating all instances on SQL installed on localhost

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to locate all instances of SQL installed on a local system.  I had one solution that worked however it didn't return consistent results.

Below worked however it wasn't consistent, Sometimes it worked on the first call. Sometimes I had to call `getSqlInstances()` multiple times.

```
public static DataTable getSqlInstances()
    {
        DataTable instances = SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(true);
        return instances;
    }
```

Below I found elsewhere (I believe another Stackoverflow post) as a recommendation from Microsoft, which I wasn't able to get it to return any results.

```
public static DataTable getSqlInstances()
    {
        System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator instances =
            System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
        DataTable dataTable = instances.GetDataSources();
        return dataTable;
    }
```

Any thoughts?

UPDATE:
I've found that below works, while not 100% consistent it's more consistent than using `SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(true)`

```
public static DataTable GetSqlInstances()
    {
        DataTable instances = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();
        return instances;
    }
```

It returns all SQL instances across the network, and not just the localhost.

Edit:

I should have looked first but the last update is pretty much the same as the method that I tried before that didn't work at all before.  Maybe I wasn't attached to a network at the time?